# the morphOne relation always return null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

im setting up a One To One (Polymorphic) like this

**My Models:**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Payement extends Model{
    protected $table = 'payements';
    protected  $primaryKey = 'id';
    public function payementable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }}

class Recu extends Model{
    protected $table = 'recus';
    protected  $primaryKey = 'id';  
    public function payement(){
        return $this->morphOne('App\Payement', 'payementable');
    }}
```

**My Tables Schemas**

```
Schema::create('recus', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
        });
Schema::create('payements', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('numero')->unique();
            $table->bigInteger('payementable_id');
            $table->string('payementable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

the problem is this is working

```
App\Payement::find(1)->payementable;
```

this return null

```
App\Recu::find(1)->payement;
```

and this return empty collection

```
Recu::first()->payement()->get()
```

Comment: Better practice is to use ```unsigned``` integer as foreign keys.
```$table->integer('payementable_id')->unsigned();``` However I am not sure it causes the problem you mentioned. Also for getting surer, you can use ```$table->morphs('payementable');``` in your migration file.

Comment: i did,not working

Comment: I did these and all the things was correct and it works properly, Pay attention if you want to get **payement** of recu you should first find objects with related **id** which exists in payement table. 
For example if your recu's id is **1**, do you have any record in the payement table with **payementable_id=1**?

Comment: App\Recu::find(1)->payement; works ?
can u do screnshoot of the data in the tables thanks

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vNH3T7t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings you presented don't have any issue. Please test with this data:

```
payements:
---------------------------------------------
|id|numero|payementable_type|payementable_id|
---------------------------------------------
|1 |1     |App\Recu         |2              |
---------------------------------------------

recus:
----
|id|
----
|1 |
----
|2 |
----
|3 |
----
```